# Parse RESTful API: curl to ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, parse-platform

I am using Parse RESTful API. I would like to append some constrains when sending a GET request with Ajax, but the examples on their websites are all written in `curl`, one example is:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: IWphomqAahPnmElGbu8k8NlXvyCCf3YItYZRD03X" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: 2RodxwlOfr1U124ZFu6yBN8bJHvDWoVc60srbOW9" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

I don't know the equivalent of `--data-urlencode` in Ajax. I have tried putting the constrains after `--data-urlencode` into Ajax call's `data`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: That means you need to url-encode the string. Try [online-tool](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/), in javascript just do [encodeURIComponent() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp). What it does is following: instead of calling `http://restapi.url?param=where={"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}` (which is incorrect) it sends: `http://restapi.url?param=where%3D%7B%22playerName%22%3A%22Sean%20Plott%22%2C%22cheatMode%22%3Afalse%7D`

Comment: `where: JSON.stringify({...})`

Comment: @skobaljic  I tried your suggestion, it works. Thanks.